# Rings Isomorphic to each other's Subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Say $R,S$ are rings, $R$ isomorphic to a subring of $S$, $S$ isomorphic to a subring of $R$, does this imply that $R$ is isomorphic to $S$? If yes, how to show that?

I tried to construct an isomorphism between R and S given the two assumed isomorphisms, but surprisingly for me, it didn't work out.

Comment: Could you tell us what you've done so far?

Comment: I tried to construct an isomorphism between R and S given the two assumed isomorphisms.

Comment: Please write what you tell me in the question, so that others can help you too

Comment: Related: [When does Cantor-Bernstein hold?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold), in mathoverflow, about when the existence of "embeddings" $A\hookrightarrow B$ and $B\hookrightarrow A$ implies the existence of an isomorphism $A\cong B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the answer is no. Consider the field $R=\mathbb{Q}(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ of rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$ in infinitely many variables, where $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the non-zero natural numbers. Let $S$ be the subring $\mathbb{Q}(x_n:n>1)[x_1]\subset R$. Then $R\not\cong S$ as rings, since $R$ is a field and $S$ is not. But $R$ is isomorphic to the subring $\mathbb{Q}(x_n:n>1)$ of $S$, via the map taking $x_{n}$ to $x_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

**Edit:** In response to your comment, here is the reason that the map $\alpha:R\to\mathbb{Q}(x_n:n>1)$ defined by extending $x_n\mapsto x_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is an isomorphism. First note that, since $R$ is a field and the codomain of $\alpha$ is a non-zero ring, $\alpha$ is [automatically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615201/showing-that-a-ring-homomorphism-from-a-field-to-a-ring-is-injective) injective. To see that $\alpha$ is surjective, let $h$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Q}(x_n:n>1)$. By definition of the field $\mathbb{Q}(x_n:n>1)$, we have $$h=\frac{f(x_{m_1},\dots,x_{m_k})}{g(x_{n_1},\dots,x_{n_l})}$$ for some $f,g\in\mathbb{Q}[x_n:n>1]$, with $g$ non-zero. Now $g(x_{n_1-1},\dots, x_{n_l-1})$ is a non-zero element of $\mathbb{Q}[x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}]$ (why?), so $$\tilde{h}:=\frac{f(x_{m_1-1},\dots,x_{m_k-1})}{g(x_{n_1-1},\dots,x_{n_l-1})}$$ is a well-defined element of $R$, and now $\alpha(\tilde{h})=h$ (why?), as desired.

Comment: Thanks, you showed that R is homomorphic to a subring of S, but how to see that this homomorphism is actually an isomorphism? Seems like it boils down to the original question.

Comment: dear @TroyMcClure, the isomorphism from $R=\mathbb{Q}(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ to $\mathbb{Q}(x_n:n>1)$ is essentially just "relabelling variables"; if you are concerned it is not an isomorphism, then I am happy to show explicitly that it is injective and surjective. but I should first ask, are you comfortable with what the elements of these rings look like?

Comment: Thanks, yes I think I fully understand the setting, and apparently my only problem is with showing that this is an isomorphism as above.

Comment: dear @TroyMcClure, I have edited to explain why this map is an isomorphism, hopefully it helps! :) I do not understand your most recent comment; yes, both $R$ and the subring of $S$ that $R$ is isomorphic to are rings. why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: @TroyMcClure here is a different way of thinking about things that might be helpful. suppose $x_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $y_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ are any variable symbols. do you see why the fields $\mathbb{Q}(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(y_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ are isomorphic? that's exactly what's going on here; just take $y_n$ to be the element $x_{n+1}\in R$. does that make sense? :)

Comment: thanks, yes I think I understand now, accepted the answer.

Comment: @TroyMcClure my pleasure, happy it helped! :) please feel free to let me know if you have any more questions, and *please* don't feel any pressure to accept the answer until you're sure you understand it!!

Comment: what led to the question was the following: let X=x1,x2,... be a sequence of infinitely many variables, Y=y1,y2,... also another sequence, does R[X] isomorphic to (R[X])[Y]? In other words, is a polynomial ring over a polynomial ring, both with infinitely many variables, isomorphic to the polynomial ring we started with? so I guess the answer is yes, now trivially by your explanations.

Comment: @TroyMcClure yes, that is exactly right! :)